# How to use OpenDatasource() to connect to a remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server, sql-server-2014

I want to SELECT some data from a remote SQL Server database which has "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries" enabled. The remote server is not a linked server to my local instance and its not in my ODBC data sources. I didn't think it had to be anyway.

However I don't understand how to get to it. I have tried this (replacing the `xx.xx.xx.xx` part with the IP address of the remote server):

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENDATASOURCE(
'SQLNCLI',
'Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx\MSSQLSERVER;User ID=SA;Password=SA;').MainDB.dbo.Product
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1:
>   SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of
>   component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is
>   turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A
>   system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed
>   Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling
>   'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'
>   in SQL Server Books Online.

The remote server has 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' for sure 100%. What am I missing? I turned SQL Server Browser on the remote server as well.

Comment: What's the message, level and state number? Also, you are certain that Ad Hoc has been enabled, are the server instance, user id and password correct as well?

Comment: @SQLHound It is Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. When I go to Surface Area Configuration it says Ad Hoc is set to true. I can connect to the remote SQL Server just fine through SSMS and see all its databases and tables.

Comment: And you tried the sp_configure commands before this query (even though I agree with you that you shouldn't have to...if it says it's open it should mean what it says)?

Comment: @SQLHound Yes I ran `sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO`. I am able to connect to the remote server as a linked server and it works fine.

Comment: Still looking... when you `EXEC sp_configure go` on it's own, the `config_value` and `run_value` are both 1?

Comment: For `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries` it says `minimum:0; maximum: 1; config_value: 1; run_value: 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80819/discussion-between-sqlhound-and-volume-one).